# Proper context attribute for a hotkey to toggle mesh display overlays?

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

I'm lost here, F.I.:

```
object_data.show_edge_crease
```

or

```
active_object.show_edge_crease
```

doesn't work...

Also, I wonder why isn't there an "add shortcut" option in the RMB menu for this kind of toggable elements?...

Comment: Try active_object.data.show_edge_crease  or edit_object.data.show_edge_crease

Comment: Thanks! that was it! So, there is no way to set a comment as the answer, right?

Comment: Made it an answer.  I Must remember to "avoid answering questions in comments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh is the data part of the active object hence,

```
active_object.data.show_edge_crease
```

or perhaps since it is the edit object:

```
edit_object.data.show_edge_crease
```

[image: info area]

Sliding down the info area header at the top to reveal the messages gives you the context paths.

As for part ii) of your question adding an "add shortcut" menu, sounds like a good idea.  This can be "*hacked*" by overriding say the edit translations operator in the menu.